# Series expansion of $\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I'm working this problem out of an old algebra book, so part of the challenge is not to use Taylor series or anything from calculus (beyond the most basic notion of limits).

Apparently the solution is,

$$\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n  = 1 - \frac{1}{2(n + 1)} - \frac{1}{(2)(3)(n + 1)^2} - \dots $$

My question is this: If

$$ \ln \left( 1 + x \right) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots$$

why can't I simply substitute $\frac{1}{n}$ for $x$ to get,

$$ \ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = n\ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) = n \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2} + \frac{1}{3n^3} - \dots \right) = 1 - \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{3n^2} \dots $$

?

Comment: What you did makes sense (though you are using the series expansion of on which seems not allowed). This doesn’t mean their answer is wrong though.

Comment: You can probably derive their formula by doing what you did to $- n \log(1-1/(n+1))$

Comment: @Eric "the series expansion of on which seems not allowed" Sorry, series expansion of what? As to your second comment, yes, that is the direction they go, eventually transforming the expression into $-(n + 1)ln(1 - \frac{1}{n + 1}) + ln(1 - \frac{1}{n + 1})$ and then expanding into series, though it's not really clear to me how the two final answers are equal.

Comment: Bleh, typo. I just mean that the infinite sum is a Taylor series from calculus which you said we can’t use.

Comment: @Eric Not exactly. The book shows how to derive the series for $ln(1 + x)$ using nothing more than the binomial series and limits to get $e$ and then the exponential and log series. Pretty slick, actually.

Answer (score 2):

You almost figured it out in the comments. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\ln \!\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n & =  - (n + 1)\ln \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n + 1}}} \right) + \ln \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n + 1}}} \right) \\ & = (n + 1)\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}} \\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^{k - 1} }}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}} \\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}} \\ & = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}} \\ & = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{{k + 1}} - \frac{1}{k}} \right)\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}} \\ & = 1 - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k(k + 1)}}\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^k }}} ,
\end{align*}
as desired. I used the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$ (wich converges for $-1<x<1$) with $x=-\frac{1}{n+1}$ though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed derivation. Dumb question--how does the $-(n + 1)$ on the RHS of line 1 become positive in line 2? More importantly, where is the misstep in my own attempt? Or is the series I came up with the same thing just in a different form?

Comment: For the first question, I expanded $-\ln(1-x)$ with $x=1/(n+1)$. Second question, you just gave an expansion in negative powers of $n$, which is correct but different from this one. One function can possess many different expansions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I like
to derive the series for
$\ln(1+x)$
is this:

$\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k
$
so
$\dfrac{1}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k+\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$
so
$\dfrac{1}{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^n (-x)^k+\dfrac{(-x)^{n+1}}{1+x}
$
or
$\dfrac{1}{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kx^k+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{1+x}
$.

Integrating from
$0$ to $t$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+t)
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{dx}{1+x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\int_0^tx^kdx+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\dfrac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{t^{k}}{k}+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1+x}dx\\
\end{array}
$

so,
replacing $n+1$ by $n$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+t)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{t^{k}}{k}
&=(-1)^{n}\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx\\
&=(-1)^{n}E_n(t)\\
\end{array}
$

where
$E_n(t)
=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx
$.

If $t > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
E_n(t)
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx\\
&<\int_0^tx^{n}dx\\
&=\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
\text{and}\\
E_n(t)
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx\\
&>\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+t}dx\\
&=\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+t)}\\
\end{array}
$

so,
if $0 < t < 1$,
$E_n(t) \to 0$
and the series converges.

Comment: In this particular problem, the Maclaurin series is needed for $-\frac{1}{2}<t<0$.

Comment: Here $t=\frac1{n}$ so $0 < t < 1$. But I see what you mean since they are deriving a different series.